# How to get these tkinter scrollbars working?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

Hi cant get these scrollbars working even though this code comes from a very advanced user on this site I have tried everything. No errors they just dont show up

```
import tkinter as tk


#Make Window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("612x417")
root.title("Exchange Rates")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.configure(background='lightgrey')
#End

#Create listboxes for currency selection
listbox1 = tk.Listbox(root, font="Helvetica 11 bold", height=3, width=10)
listbox2 = tk.Listbox(root, font="Helvetica 11 bold", height=3, width=10)

#Try to create a scroll bar
scrollbar1 = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=listbox1.yview)
listbox1.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)

scrollbar2 = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=listbox2.yview)
listbox2.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)

listbox1.place(x=300,y=50)
listbox2.place(x=300,y=125)



scrollbar3 = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar3.pack(side="right", fill="y")

listbox = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar3.set)
listbox.pack()

scrollbar3.config(command=listbox.yview)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: those are the closest I have got to succeeding

Comment: This code doesn't run because of this error: `NameError: name 'Scrollbar' is not defined`. When I fix that I get `NameError: name 'Listbox' is not defined`.  Are these errors what you're asking about? Also, your listbox is empty -- what do you think the scrollbar will do? It can't scroll anything because there's nothing to scroll.

Comment: No not at all in fact I get zero errors all the listboxes have values and are in the right place but just no scroll bars ALSO its not the full code as I was trying to keep it short. full code here pastebin.com/zB1MVmKC

Comment: incase that link didnt work heres a new one https://pastebin.com/Ns2AijMW

Comment: The code in your question absolutely will not run. Please don't post unrunable code, and don't link to code on another site. Please create a [mcve], and focus on both _minimal_ and _complete_.

Comment: So I gotta create one piece of code for the website and one for me to use ok

Comment: We do not care about your real code. We care about the smallest code possible that accurately reproduces your problem. If you want a code review of your actual code, post to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Everybody else does all that stuff pastebin etc this website is how i learnt about the site the reason i post full app code (previously )is because im constantly trying to work in to my code tiny pieces of other peoples which are harder to put into code if people can see everything they can see where im going wrong PS the exact code above works for me in SPYDER IDE shows all listboxes with no scroll bars

Comment: The posted code can't possibly work unless you run in an environment that has some other libraries imported. If you're doing that, you need to mention that in the question. Take the posted code, run it through a normal python interpreter, and it absolutely will fail. I can't possibly know that you use spyder if you don't mention it.

Comment: i am new to asking questions forgot to mention was IDE SPYDER and the only other library or whatever I am using is Tkinter there is literally no other code I can see in there. Thanks for the code review heads up DID not know it was there will bookmark

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you managed to run it without an error because you imported tkinter as tk but for listbox you put Listbox (not tk.Listbox) or for scrollbar3 you put Scrollbar (not tk.Scrollbar). Also they don't show up because you haven't packed/placed them! 
And... you have to use either place, pack or grid you can't use them together. You used `.place()` for your listbox1 and 2 but then you used `.pack()` for your scrollbar3 and listbox. Whatever you use first (here it's place) will work but the others  just simply won't show up.

Comment: will attempt to stop being so n00b was trying different permutations

Answer (score 0):

The below script should hopefully show you how `Scrollbar`s work in a clear and concise way and how they are affected by the number of items entered into a `listbox`

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.top = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.frame = Frame(self.top)
        self.entry = Entry(self.master)
        self.button = Button(self.master, text="Ok", command=self.command)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.top.withdraw()
        self.frame.pack()
    def command(self):
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = Frame(self.top)
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.frame)
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient="vertical", command=self.listbox.yview)
        self.listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        for i in range(int(self.entry.get())):
            self.listbox.insert(END, "Col"+str(i))
        self.frame.pack()
        self.listbox.pack(side="left")
        self.scroll.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill=Y)
        self.top.deiconify()

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Also please take into account that in order for us to review a problem and help you work through it, we need to be able to run and review the code in an easy and digestible fashion.

Comment: yes i have been trying to figure out how to refine my questions for you.

Comment: Could not get code to run application window opens but nt responding have not had much luck at all in my configuratin of Spyder and Python 3.6 with any "self" stuff ever in this code or others

Comment: I can assure you, if you run this in the Python 3.6 IDE it will work

Answer (score 0):

Hello people answering my own question, here is a working `Listbox` within a `Frame` with a `Scrollbar`.

```
import tkinter as tk

#Make Window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("612x417")
root.title("Exchange Rates")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.configure(background='lightgrey')
#End

#Try to create a listbox with a scroll bar within a frame

#Create elements
frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=1, relief='sunken', width=150, height=300)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame)
listbox = tk.Listbox(frame)

#Attach listbox to scrollbar
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

#Poulate listbox
for i in range(100):
    listbox.insert('end', i)

#Pack elements
frame.pack(side='top')
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
listbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```